# Match rows between two matrices

Tags: r

Having a matrix A like:

```
       [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
 [1,]   121  114   117   200 
 [2,]   312  215    78   211
 [3,]   413  121   719   117
 [4,]   511  615   428   212
 [5,]   616  816   114   223
 [6,]   117  428   121   211
```

and a matrix B like:

```
      [,1] [,2] 
[1,]   117  121
```

I want to get only the rows from A where each row of B exists in rows of A. The result should be:

```
1. row [1]
2. row [3]
3. row [6]
```

Comment: Is matrix B always a vector of values? You say "each row of B" but don't describe what the output would be for a multirow case. Also, it's not clear if B might have NAs (since one row might have two values to match and another would have three).

Comment: Based on the example, another option is `A[rowSums(matrix(A %in% B, ncol = ncol(A)))==ncol(B),]`

Comment: there are no NAs in A and B. Also matrix B will be a one row matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A[apply(A, 1, function(x) all(B[1,] %in% x)),]   
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  121  114  117  200
#[2,]  413  121  719  117
#[3,]  117  428  121  211
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the most elegant way but it works!

```
rows<-vector()
j<-1
for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
  temp<-A[i,]
  aux<- which(B %in% temp)
  if(length(aux)!=0){
    rows[j]<-i
    j<-j+1
  }

}
```